# Grails Set Error Message From messages.properties In External JavaScript File

Tags: javascript, java, grails, internationalization, formvalidation-plugin

How can I set error message on **external java script file** from **messages.properties** file so error message will change automatically based on local or language like English, German etc.

How Can I use **`<g:message code="" default="" />`** or **`${message(code:'',default:'')}`** on **external java script file**?

Answer (score 0):

In my application I pass a model object to a javascript in the following way:

```
<g:javascript>
    // Scroll the page to the position of the add button clicked by the user
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            window.scrollBy(0, ${pageScroll}); 
        });     
</g:javascript>
```

In your example you can define a new variable using the tag

```
<g:set var="tranlsatedLabel" value="${g.message(..)}"/>
```

and the you can pass it like I show above.

Comment: Yes, sure we will use it on GSP file but not in any external java script file.

Comment: Ok, if your external javascript file is not rendered by grails then it doesn't work. There is only one solution, you should implement a controller working as a rest service. There are some grails plugin for this problem and they use a "REST service" approach.